# Validation Error: Redefined outer name from outer scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, pylint

Not sure I get this but I got a validation error from pyLint saying:

```
Redefining name 'a' from outer scope (line 443) (redefined-outer-name)
Redefining name 'b' from outer scope (line 444) (redefined-outer-name)
```

The code is like this:

```
a = 98  # line 443
b = 90  # line 444

def prodNr(a, b):
    """Definiera prodNr"""
    return a * b

result = prodNr(a, b)

ANSWER = result
```

Could anyone please give me a clue on how to get rid of the validation error?

Comment: Where are the indentations ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843079/redifine-name-from-outer-scope-python3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call you variables something else:

```
def prodNr(a, b):
    """
    Definiera prodNr
    """

    return a * b
i = 98
j = 90
result = prodNr(i, j)
```

You can use any name for the variables you pass in they don't have to be called `a` and `b`. It does not affect your code either way as the variables are passed into the function, it would be a problem if you had a and b in multiple places in your code and you decided to change `a` to `var_a` but forgot to change it in one or two places then you would get different output to what you would expect.

Comment: How is that, sorry for asking? Does the function replace the value a, b with i, j?

Comment: whatever you pass into the function as arguments will be `a` and `b` in the body, when you pass `i,j` `a` will refer to `i` in the body and `b` to `j`